# Nested objects and collection size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, size, nested-attributes

I run into a weird issue since I upgraded to Rails 3.2.

My application have some objects managed with nested_forms, but when i try to reach a collection's size after having built a new nested object, the nested object is taken in count.

For ex.:

```
1.9.3p0 :004 > e = Expense.last
  Expense Load (22.6ms)  (...)
 => #<Expense id: 1, (...)
1.9.3p0 :005 > e.comments.size
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) (...)
 => 0 
1.9.3p0 :006 > e.comments.build
 => #<Comment id: nil, content: nil, commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: "Expense", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, creator_id: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :007 > e.comments.size
 => 1
```

In this case, I expect the `e.expense.size` to return 0 since the `Comment`object has not been saved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Building the comment creates ... 1 comment.  It doesn't exist in the database (yet) so `e.commment.count` would return 0, but it exists in the application, so `size` returns 1.  So that sort of makes sense.

But I do see there's a little potentially unexpected result here.  If a comment doesn't exist in memory, it looks like Rails checks with the DB (the `SELECT COUNT(*)...`), whereas if it finds one in memory it does not.

I wonder what would happen if you had several existing comments already, then checked `e.comments.size` in that case?

Which version of Rails were you coming from that worked differently?

Comment: Maybe it's not since the upgrade, maybe i just did not notice it before. The fact is that i get into this behaviour when i call `for comment in e.comments`, and since the comment that has been just built is not yet saved, it raise some error too